# How can I zip groups of files based on first x characters of filename?

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003, 7-zip

I have a single directory into which log files are dumped, in this fashion:

```
20160701_file001.log
20160701_file002.log
20160702_file001.log
...
20160801_file001.log
20160801_file002.log
20160801_file003.log
...
```

Could you advise of a single loop that could be run under the parent directory in Command Prompt, which would zip all files for 201607 only, naming the zip file (which would be located in the same place) using the name of the oldest file to be zipped?

This would give 31 files for July, as each day would have it's own ZIP file (attempting to zip them all results in a 'too many files to zip' error).

EDIT: It seems my SuperUser etiquette is not yet up to scratch as I'm getting comments all across the site from the same user, pointing me to the many 'How to..' documents published.. Apologies to all!

Please find the script I'm using below - this only zips one days' worth at a time and I'm looking for help in adapting it to e.g. do a whole month's worth of log files located in the same directory..

```
7z.exe a -tzip 20160731_file001.log.zip 201607*_file*.log
```

Comment: Yes, but ... please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the tips @DavidPostill - I've amended the question asked to better communicate the issue at hand..

Comment: Your question is still not clear. 1/. "This would give 31 files for July, as each day would have it's own ZIP file" and 2/ "using the name of the oldest file to be zipped" are not both possible at the same time. 31 files cannot all have the same name.

Comment: 7zip doesn't have a delete or move function, so you'd have to write a batch to work around that feature gap. You can zip current month easily using date variable in DOS. It's not easy though to run a batch file on Aug 1, wanting to zip previous month... DOS is not that smart... https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/835-zip-7zip-files-with-date-and-move-very-simple-and-works ... for manual zipping, I just use `7za a 201607 201607*.log` <- this should zip all your log files for July into one zip file.